# regular expression to find string

Tags: regex, eclipse

Can someone help me with the regular expression to find and replace a particular code inside a large project in eclipse I am working on:

**Eg**: I want to select all code that contains following "`new ArrayList<some value..>();`"

**Like:**

```
new ArrayList<Content>();

new ArrayList<User>();

new ArrayList<Content_User_Mapping>();
```

---

**and replace with:**

```
new ArrayList<Content>(0);

new ArrayList<User>(0);

new ArrayList<Content_User_Mapping>(0);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `ArrayList<(.*)>\(\)` with `ArrayList<$1>(0)`.

What to keep in mind when dealing with the search and replace dialog:

- The find-field (when using regular expressions) expects a regular expression so

  - `(` and `)` are special and needs to be escaped
  - `(...)` represents a *group*
- The replace field does *not* have special treatement for `(` and `)`, but allows you to refer to the captured groups by `$n`.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. . . I am unable to accept the answer, will accept in 10mins